# Android build error - java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android, windows, macos, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This android project created on windows machine, setup a MacOS build machine and fetching the folders from Git and building it in Mac.

Here is the problem when I execute the gradle on mac.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app' is the error occurring.
What do you think could cause this?

```
/gradlew tasks --stacktrace
Observed package id 'build-tools;25.0.2' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/build-tools/25.0.2' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2')
Observed package id 'build-tools;26.0.1' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/build-tools/26.0.1' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/build-tools/26.0.1')
Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/emulator' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/emulator')
Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/extras/android/m2repository' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository')
Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/extras/google/m2repository' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository')
Observed package id 'extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2')
Observed package id 'extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2')
Observed package id 'patcher;v4' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/patcher/v4' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/patcher/v4')
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/platform-tools' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/platform-tools')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-25' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/platforms/android-25' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/platforms/android-25')
Observed package id 'platforms;android-26' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/platforms/android-26' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/platforms/android-26')
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools' (Expected '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/tools')

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$ArrayBasedBuilder.add(ImmutableCollection.java:339)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$Builder.add(ImmutableList.java:652)
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.updateRepositories(DefaultSdkLoader.java:470)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.collectArtifacts(DependencyManager.java:501)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveConfiguration(DependencyManager.java:354)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:263)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:166)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:375)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createVariantData$3(VariantManager.java:607)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:603)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:793)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:487)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:263)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:601)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:596)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
        ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.926 secs
```

Comment: I see resolving dependencies mentioned several times in the stack trace.  Maybe when you ported to MacOS you neglected a configuration step to bring in your old dependencies.

Comment: i am window user, you can try to delete your build folder and then clean/Rebuild. most of time it help me on window along with all dependencies you integrated.Hope, it may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Those warnings looked like just to notify to me. They are not looking like big deal.(I guess) what did you mean by "Maybe when you ported to MacOS you neglected a configuration step to bring in your old dependencies" @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Project has been developed in windows tho but build machine is MacOS so there is no android studio setup on the build machine. Works the build out on command line such as "./gradlew build" @UchihaSasuke